# Last entry in a row not blank

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hey There I'm trying to figure out the sql code for this:

Assuming I have 4 columns:

```
ID  NAME  EMAIL
1   Mike  mike@mike.com
2   Bob   bob@bob.com
3   Chris
4   Matt
```

I want to select the last entry not null from email so in this instance it would be looking for bob@bob.com
I tried Coalesce but that seemed to give me values from the column, but not the LAST one entered. MAX I think is only used to ID's. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By joining against a subquery which returns only the `MAX(ID)`. This isn't necessary in MySQL, but many other RDBMS won't permit you to include columns other than the aggregate if they are not also in a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT yourtable.*
FROM
  yourtable
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID FROM yourtable WHERE EMAIL IS NOT NULL) maxid ON yourtable.ID = maxid.ID
```

Note: In either case this only works reliably if your `ID` is an auto-incrementing column and you have not meddled with it by inserting rows where previous ids had been deleted.